# Использование своего профиля Firefox в Selenium+Java

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, profile

Как вытащить свой профиль firefox и запустить тест, используя этот профиль, при условии, что тест запускается на разных машинах и везде имя профиля будет разным, но профиль юзерский только один. Дефолтный анонимный, который использует селениум не устраивает.

Comment: А в чем конкретно вопрос? Как запустить драйвер с определенным профилем или как определять имя профиля на разных машинах? Если второе, то, как вариант, на каждой машине создать переменную среды с именем профиля, и из теста к ней обращаться

Comment: Как определить имя профиля на машине и запустить тест с этим профилем. Возможности создать переменную среды нет.